# Django template counting days from now to specific date

Tags: django, django-models, django-templates

I have a model with DateField:

```
end_date = models.DateField(default=datetime.date.today)
```

In the template I need to calculate how many days there is to the end_date from now.
I tried:

```
{% now "d m Y"|timeuntil:placement.end_date|date:"d m Y" %}
```

but it doesn't work. How can I get number of days until that date?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a limitation to using Django functionality in Templates. You could solve this by combining the [timesince and timuntil](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#timeuntil) methods to calculate the difference between two dates. However you would benefit more from doing this in a python view and then pass the result to the template.

This way you can truly use the power of Datetime. So in your views.py and the specific function that renders the template, include this:

```
d0 = datetime.now().date()
d1 = placement.end_date
delta = d0 - d1
print delta.days
```

You can read more about the Datetime documentation [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.now). Now you can pass that variable along in a context, or by itself to be rendered by the template

Comment: I'm familiar with timeuntil filter but I'm trying to calculate difference between current date and placement.end_date. end_date is always in the future (default=datetime.date.today is only for example)

Comment: Does this come closer to what you want to do?

Answer (score 2):

**Option 1: Create a custom filter**

Create a custom filter function which grabs the current date and calculates the days.

In your template you simply use:

```
{{ placement.end_date | days_until }}
```

To define and register the filter, include this code in a python file:

```
from datetime import datetime
from django import template

register = template.Library()

@register.filter
def days_until(date):
    delta = datetime.date(date) - datetime.now().date()
    return delta.days
```

More about Django custom template tags and filters [here.](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/howto/custom-template-tags/)

**Option 2: Calculate the days in your view and store it in the context**

This is straightforward for one date. You calculate the days and store the information in the context:

```
from datetime import datetime
delta = placement.end_date - datetime.now().date()
context['days_left'] = delta.days
```

In your template you access it directly:

```
{{ days_left }}
```

But, if you want to pass a list of "placements" to the template, you will have to "attach" this new information to every placement. This is a different topic and the implementation depends on the project... you can create a wrapper over placement... or store the days_left in a different dictionary...

Answer (score 2):

Because I like Django built-in filters

> **timesince**
>
> Formats a date as the time since that date (e.g., “4 days, 6 hours”).
>
> Takes an optional argument that is a variable containing the date to
> use as the comparison point (without the argument, the comparison
> point is now). For example, if blog_date is a date instance
> representing midnight on 1 June 2006, and comment_date is a date
> instance for 08:00 on 1 June 2006, then the following would return “8
> hours”:

```
{{ blog_date|timesince:comment_date }}
```

> Comparing offset-naive and offset-aware datetimes will return an empty
> string.
>
> Minutes is the smallest unit used, and “0 minutes” will be returned
> for any date that is in the future relative to the comparison point.